# Storing pandas dataframe in a local machine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
  File         Hour

  test1          0
  test2          1
  test1          1
```

I am trying to convert it to json and then store it in a local file location using the below command:

```
df1.to_json("\home\user1\Desktop\jsonfiles\df1.json")
```

But the file does not get saved in the above location. Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: either replace "\" with "/" or use: `r"\home\user1\Desktop\jsonfiles\df1.json"`

Comment: I have tried replacing \ wiht /, it did not work out. Now i also tried adding r in front of it, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find your CSV file (if it was successfully written to disk, otherwise please post a full error stack) this way:

```
In [40]: fn = '/home/user1/Desktop/jsonfiles/df1.json'

In [41]: df.to_json(fn)

In [42]: f = open(fn)

In [43]: import os

In [44]: print(os.path.abspath(f.name))
C:\temp\aa.csv
```

Comment: The error is "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/users/Desktop/df1.json' ". But the path exists. Not sure why i am getting this error message.

Comment: @user3447653, i've changed my answer - please try to follow exactly the procedure...

Comment: After I execute the second statement, I get the error "No such file or directory: /temp/aa.csv"

Comment: @user3447653, are you on Linux?